# What type of lizard is this?

Tags: species-identification

The photo was taken in southern Florida.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It may be green anoles (*[Anolis carolinensis](http://effectivewildlifesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/anolis_carolinensis.jpg)*). They are [harmless](http://effectivewildlifesolutions.com/florida-lizards/) I think...

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a green anole. Very common in FL. Also called chameleon because they can change color from green to brown, and back again!